# Javascript - How to get the ID of a button clicked

Tags: javascript

I've searched around Stack Overflow for a couple of hours and seen similar questions asked but none of the supplied solutions are quite what I'm looking for, or just plain don't work.

So I'm trying to get the ID of a button which sits under a certain div using Javascript ONLY and not using any Javascript within the HTML code.

My HTML code looks like this:

```
         <div id="constants" class="hidden">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Gas</legend>
                <div>
                    <div class="daily_charge">
                        <p>Daily charge: <span id="gasDaily"></span></p>
                        <button id="gasDaily_Edit">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rate_charge">
                        <p>Gas rate: <span id="gasRate"></span></p>
                        <button id="gasRate_Edit">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Elec</legend>
                <div>
                    <div class="daily_charge">
                        <p>Daily charge: <span id="elecDaily"></span></p>
                        <button id="elecDaily_Edit">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rate_charge">
                        <p>Elec rate: <span id="elecRate"></span></p>
                        <button id="elecRate_Edit">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>                         
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Water</legend>
                <div>
                    <div class="daily_charge">
                        <p>Daily charge: <span id="waterInDaily"></span></p>
                        <button id="waterInDaily_Edit">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rate_charge">
                        <p>Water rate: <span id="waterInRate"></span></p>
                        <button id="waterInRate_Edit">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
```

and the Javascript I've been trying to use unsuccessfully is:

```
var constantsDiv = document.getElementById("constants");
var constants_button = constantsDiv.getElementsByTagName("button");
var button_count = constants_button.length;

 for (var i = 0; i <= button_count; i += 1) {
    constants_button[i].onclick = function (e) {    
        alert(this.id);
    }; 
};
```

For a start I'm not sure putting it in a for loop is entirely the right way but I get an 'Unable to set property 'onclick' of undefined or null reference' anyway.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Change `<=` to `<`. Array/lists are always 0-based. Also, where/when/how is the this code executed? Is it executed before the elements exist by any chance?

Comment: Can u plz describe more?

Comment: Did you place the code on the onload of the window?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: What's the value of `button_count`?

Comment: @FelixKling the value is 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for()` statement will crash in the last element. Change removing the `=` sign in the condition:

```
for (var i = 0; i < button_count; i += 1) {
===================^
```

Comment: Even though it crashes, the handlers bound in the previous iterations should work fine. I believe the code is executed before the elements exist.

Comment: You're right @FelixKling , but I think that avoiding errors in javascript console can help to debug it. Maybe it's the problem of DOM not ready. Let OP explain and we'll see :) Thank you

Comment: And it was as simple as that! Thank you very much.

@FelixKling - the elements are already in place when the code is executed, but thanks for the input.

Comment: @FelixKling I know...couldn't work it out for the life of me. It's always the little things!

Answer (score 0):

Try This ,

document.getElementByID("#id").value

Comment: There is no element with ID `id` here, and why should `value` be accessed when the OP wants the ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can use: e.target.id

```
for (var i = 0; i < button_count; i += 1) {
    constants_button[i].onclick = function (e) {    
        alert(e.target.id);
    }; 
};
```

Comment: Why is this better than `this.id`? Or put differently: Why does `this.id` not work?

Comment: @FelixKling With `event delegation` `this` and `target` may be different.

Comment: For those who have to support IE8 still (and there are a few), `var target = e.target || e.srcElement;`

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher: But there is no event delegation here. The OP wants the ID of the button, not the element that was targeted inside the button.

Comment: @FelixKling event.target is a reference to the element that triggered the event.

Comment: Right, but the OP wants the ID of the element the handler is bound to.

Comment: @FelixKling That's what it is doing. The onclick binds that function to the element click event. Therefore, the target for that single event function is the element it is bound to. The function for that onclick event won't trigger when another button is clicked. The elements are not in the proper order for one click event to bubble up to another button.

Comment: @FelixKling And even if they were bubbling up, the e.target remains the original element that triggered the event, so I'm confused at what you are trying to say. [Here is proof that event.target remains the same](https://jsfiddle.net/6o210tv0/)

Comment: Here is an example where it is not the same: https://jsfiddle.net/6o210tv0/1/ . But  at least in the OP's case it would be same. But then, why change something that already works? Using `e.target` instead of `this` doesn't solve the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with this:

```
e.target.getAttribute("id")
```

Where `e` is the variable in your function to handle the event.

Comment: In the case `this` refers to the own function object, not the targeted HTML element (or I think so...)

Comment: That's incorrect. `this` **never** refers to the function itself, unless it is **explicitly** set so. `this` refers to the DOM element the handler is bound to.

Answer (score 0):

Add a function which create a data-click element on clicked button (with class), then find data and her value...

```
$(".btnToClick").on("click", function {
    $(this).data('click', true);
})
```

and

```
$(".btnToClick [data-click=true]").val();
```

i wrote with JQuery

Answer (score -1):

Try this one
    alert($(this).id)

Comment: What exactly is `$`?

Comment: Example for worst practices )